# Error while connecting Eclipse IDE to run the Flex 4.5.1 SDK

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, syntax-error

I want to run the Flex SDK 4.5.1 on Eclipse IDE. I have followed this http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/
step by step and it was same as it was written.

But then when i first built my sample code and ran it, it gave me these errors. I cant figure out what the problem is:

This is the sample code:

and these are the ERRORS:
Loading configuration file C:\Mario's Files\STF\Flex SDK\flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328\frameworks\flex-config.xml
_application_Styles.as(24): col: 38 Error: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before s.

```
[Embed(_resolvedSource='C:/Mario's Files/STF/Flex SDK/flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328/frameworks/libs/framework.swc$Assets.swf', symbol='mx.skins.cursor.BusyCursor', source='C:/Mario's Files/STF/Flex SDK/flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328/frameworks/libs/framework.swc$Assets.swf', original='Assets.swf', _line='194', _pathsep='true', _file='C:/Mario's Files/STF/Flex SDK/flex_sdk_4.5.1.21328/frameworks/libs/framework.swc$defaults.css')]
                                 ^
```

Any solutions?
Do we have to get a compatible Eclipse-FlexSDK-Flash version??

Answer (score 2):

The ' in "Mario's Files" throws off the parser, because it assumes the path ends there. Your folder names should not have a ' in it, ever. Call the folder "Marios Files" and you're fine.

Read up on **String delimiters** and **escape characters**, it's knowledge you will need anyway at some point.

This question might also be off-topic.

Comment: ya got it... actually the address was fine.. there was some problem with me compilet arguments... added the " -keep " argument to separate the as .files

Comment: But i have several other small issues...

The folder structure rite now with me is only 
PRoject
- bin
- libs
- src

I want to add the extended folder for themes, plugins, extra namespace files, and other components...
i have module of code but i dont know where to integrate or import it from

Also autoindentation isnt working at all.. is there a free plugin..?